# List bullet image position in Mac Safari

Tags: css

I am having an issue with bullet image position in Mac Safari. In Windows, it looks fine in all browsers but in Mac, the bullet image seems to stay at the **bottom** of the `<li>`.

```
.content ul {
   font-size: 1.4em;
   list-style-position: outside;
   list-style-type: none;
   padding: 0;
}

.content ul li {
  background: url("../images/bullet.jpg") no-repeat scroll left center rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  padding-left:15px;
}
```

I've also tried using `left 50%` for the position but it does not seem to have any effect.

Comment: If the problem is vertical alignment, then why do you think horizontal placement will fix the problem?

Comment: @TylerH Sorry I don't get it. Are you referring to `padding-left`? That wasn't for fixing the vertical alignment. That was just there to have the left spacing.

Comment: No, I'm referring to `left 50%` that you say you've tried.

Comment: It is working for me in Safari 8.0 (mac). Do you have any other css related to this list? By the way, the correct way of writing the background property is this: `background: color | image | repeat | attachment | position` so you're css can be simplified like this: `background: transparent url("../images/bullet.jpg") no-repeat left center` as background-attachment is set to `scroll` by default and a color that is `rgba(0,0,0,0)` is transparent.

Comment: @Pipo I have updated the CSS in my question. That's basically what I have. The bullet image is off by about 2-3 pixels in Mac. With the background property, I have also tried separate background attributes such as `background-image`, `background-position`, etc.

Comment: What if you remove your `list-style-position: outside;` ? You don't need it as your `list-style-type` is set to `none`. Which version of Safari are you using by the way?

Comment: @Pipo I initially did not have that. I just tried using it. No effect of having or removing it. I am testing on different versions Yosemite, Maverick, etc. All having the same issue. Safari in Windows look fine. Is there a media query to target Safari in Mac?

Comment: @user1448031 No there is no way to target Safari with CSS, you have to use Javascript for that. Can you post a jsfiddle reproducing the issue? As I can't see it on my Safari it is really hard to help you...